# Execution failed for task 'app:dexDebug'

Tags: android

I recently tried testing local backend support on my app and have faced some gradle build issues. Below is the error I am getting:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

**Here is my Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="yassin.marc.guardianreader.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Here is the build.gradle (app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    //applicationId 
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

**And here is build.gradle (backend):**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
}
repositories {
jcenter();
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
dependencies {
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
}

appengine {
downloadSdk = true
appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
}
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
}
```

I tried removing redundant dependencies but haven't found success in that. I'm wondering if you guys could give me some help! Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I had something similar not long ago - and it may not relate to your problem - but Android Studio does not support Java 1.8 too well. I had to revert back to 1.7 to get my project compile properly.

Comment: I had similar problem, using build tools version 23 preview worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. I added

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

to defaultconfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    //applicationId
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: I have added. But it didn`t work for me. Could you please suggest?